# NodeJS spawn `open` doesn't actually open the file

Tags: node.js

I've got a report `.html` file which I'd like to open using a CLI command. 
For this I have a file located at `./folder/report.html`

Normally using the command `open ./folder/report.html` directly in the terminal, it works perfectly fine, and the file would be opened in the browser.

However, using `spawn` it doesn't quite work the same. It just *doesn't* open the file at all.

```
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

spawn('open', ['./folder/report.html']);
```

Is there anything wrong with this piece of code?

I'm using spawn for other commands as well, and in this case it seems to be working fine. Example of working spawn:

```
spawn('backstop', ['test', '--config', './folder/config.json'])
```

I don't see the differences in the `spawn` process here.

Comment: I can't reproduce it. Are you sure `./folder/report.html` exists? Are you sure your `require('process').cwd()` is where you think it should be? (Also, you may want to tag [tag:macos] as appropriate, as `open` means something different for different OSes.)

Comment: I've been looking at this for days. I just found the issue. The function that calls this `spawn` command, was nested in a function. `() => () => spawn()`. Should've been `() => spawn()`. This wasn't the case for my other `spawns`. I feel stupid now. Thanks for the suggestion, it made me look in the right direction. Removing the nested function fixed it, and the `spawn open` command is working now.

Comment: @hespen feel free to close your question :)